# ContextMenu RadScheduler telerik 2017

Tags: telerik, radscheduler

how can I intercept the value 1 of the submenu telerik radscheduler on the server side to redirect the page to print?

```
                <AppointmentContextMenus>
                   <telerik:RadSchedulerContextMenu runat="server" ID="ContextMenu1">
                       <Items>
                           <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Open" Value="CommandEdit" />
                           <telerik:RadMenuItem IsSeparator="True" />
                           <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Print" Value="CommandPrint" />
                           <telerik:RadMenuItem IsSeparator="True" />
                           <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Delete" Value="CommandDelete" />
                       </Items>
                   </telerik:RadSchedulerContextMenu>

               </AppointmentContextMenus>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved thanks

Private Sub RadScheduler1_AppointmentContextMenuItemClicked(sender As Object, e As AppointmentContextMenuItemClickedEventArgs) Handles RadScheduler1.AppointmentContextMenuItemClicked

```
    If e.MenuItem.Value = "1" Then
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx?id=1")
    End If

End Sub
```